# Change div size base on javascript window.resize if innerWidth < 1300

Tags: javascript, response

I'm trying to create some responsive elements based on the innerWidth of the client browser.

For example if the innerWidth is less than 1300px I want the div to increase in size, else I want it to hold it's initial CSS value.

I've tried the code below which actively tracks the client innerWidth size but does not change the element when the specific value is reached.

I'm essentially trying to incorporate responsive elements at certain breakpoints.

```
function clientWidth(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(width);

};


var widthResult = clientWidth();

window.onresize = clientWidth;

var row1_col_3 = document.getElementById('row1_col_3');

if(widthResult < 1300){
      row1_col_3.style.width = "450px";
} else{
      row1_col_3.style.width = "300px";
    };
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with JS and not CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** for this, not JavaScript.

Run the snippet below and then click the "Full page" link at the top, right of the snippet window. You will see the background color change from yellow to green (assuming your screen is at least 1300px wide).

```css
/* Default style */
div {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:250px;
}
  

/* Style for when viewport is at least 1300px wide */
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  div {
    background-color:green;
    width:750px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to change the size of elements as I resize the browser, not the type of device running the page. I simply want the element to increase in size if the innerWidth is less than a certain pixel value and return to it's default when the innerWidth value is exceeded again, is this still a media query?

Comment: @ACSpeed Media Queries are device independent. They can do exactly what you are asking. Did you follow my instructions to see the snippet work? It is changing the style (any aspect of the style that you like) simply based on the width of the viewport, not the device.

Comment: I did and I've seen that media query snippet before but when I tried to alter width it didn't work. I'll retry and look at my code. Out of interest can this be done with JS? Thanks for the help

Comment: @ACSpeed I just updated my snippet to also adjust the width. You can see it works just fine.

Comment: @ACSpeed This can be done with JS, but it is much more efficient, scalable and simple to use Media Queries.